# Sequent calculus as multilinear/tensor algebra?

Tags: category-theory, type-theory, sequent-calculus, linear-logic

**Settings**

I have been studying sequent calculus for several months and found that there should be a **rule** that is seemingly typical, even too trivial, but/hence no one officially mentions:

$$
\dfrac{
 a : A, b : B
}{
a, b : A, B
}.
\tag{1}
$$

This seems mere syntax sugar and actually often used in this conventional form:

$$
\vec{x} : \vec{X}
\tag{2}
$$

as representing:

$$
x_1 : X_1, \dots, x_n : X_n
\tag{3}
$$

where there seems to be more appropriate one:

$$
\vec{x : X}.
\tag{4}
$$

By the way, this writing convention $(1)$ performs obviously poor as syntax sugar for heterogeneous A, B, ..., Z since when it becomes longer, you would need to carefully match each element with its own type on each different side of a statement:

$$
a, b, \dots, z : A, B, \dots, Z.
\tag{5}
$$

**Question**

My curious question, or intuition, for the whole system of sequent calculus, is:

1. Whether we can consider or utilise the rule $(1)$ already as the **tensor product introduction**, instead of letting it be mere syntax sugar.
2. Whether we can introduce **sum types** $+$, **product types** $×$, **function types** $→$ and any other possible ones as parallel to those operations on vectors such as addition, inner product, outer product, element-wise product, Kronecker product, norm, trace, etc.., without loss of generality.

**Notes**

The proper interpretation of $a, b : A, B$ might be different depending on which side of $⊢$ it is in, the former being **tensor product** and the latter something like **direct sum**.

The semantics here is most likely given by [polycategory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/polycategory).

Comment: i don t see the point.  a:A,b:B has exactly the same information as a,b:A,B. you declare two variables for two types. what IS different  is when tou are allowed to form AxB:Type and can declare v:AxB.

Comment: there are notes by mike shulman "categorical logic from the categorical point of view" they stress the similarities between the syntax of type theory and multicategories a lot. maybe you would like to look into them